# How to get window size with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I use `"cypress": "2.1.0"` for website functional test.

Also I have condition in tests:

```
if (WIDTH < 1025 && WIDTH > 480) {
  it('Open search sidebar', function () {
    cy.wait(500);
    cy.get('.FilterStroke_resultsLabel_7gBlM').safeClick();
  });
}
```

My question is how to get screen size `(WIDTH, HEIGHT)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on how you are using viewPorts. If you are using [cy.viewport(...)](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html#Syntax) command, then you are easily able to store arguments to a variable.

However, I'm assuming, that you are trying to get width and height of the browser without explicitly setting viewport before the test.
In this way, cypress takes the default windows width and height from the configuration.

You are able to access the [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Name-and-Value) trough the global `Cypress` variable, e.g.:

```
Cypress.config("viewportWidth") // => 800

OR

Cypress.config().viewportWidth // => 800
```

Comment: What if I used the presets with cy.viewport() and want to know if the current width is lower/higher than a set number? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @JanessaLabeur maybe in your case this could work:
`cy.window().then(win => cy.log(win.innerWidth + ' x ' + win.innerHeight))`?

Answer (score -1):

You could also get what is *actually being displayed at the time* rather than the global default configuration with:

```js
const WIDTH = window.innerWidth
```

This matches the viewport dimensions displayed by Cypress wherever I have tested it.  There is a matching `innerHeight` property if needed.

Comment: I don't think the global window object is the same object in your test files so not sure if this actually works how you think it does